# How to search env var in powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

bash:

> $> env | grep "lib"

How to do it in powershell?

I tried but doesn't work:

> ps1> get-childitem env:\ | foreach-object { if ($_.Value -contains 'Lib') {write-output $_.Name }  }

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
get-childitem env:\ | Where-Object {$_.Value -Match "Lib"}
```